# Make EditText hint all caps

Tags: android, android-edittext, uppercase

I want to make the EditText hint appear in capital case characters without adding an upper case string in the strings file, Any help?

Comment: Only hint or always?

Comment: `android:hint="Your Hint Text"` ...

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto Always

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is an example you can try:

```
myEditText.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.your_text_in_string).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: no way I can do something like this in the layout XML?

Comment: @SherifElNady I think the only way is do it programmatically (my answer) if you want to get from strings file :)

Comment: disappointed that I have to resort to setting this one thing programmatically..but thanks for the suggestion!